# ERROR with building wheels for greenlet, mysqlclient which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-python

I have installed Python 3.11.3 on my laptop with Windows 11. I'm trying to work on a problem statement(order placement backend implementation) using Flask. As part of this work, when I try to install the requirements.txt, I'm getting the below error.

```
 fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

...
...
...

 MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]


  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build greenlet mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for greenlet, mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`
```

Here is requirements.txt content. I have created a virtual environment and trying to install these requirements in that.

```
aniso8601==9.0.1
apispec==5.1.1
click==8.0.3
Flask==2.0.2
flask-apispec==0.11.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
marshmallow==3.13.0
mysqlclient==2.0.3
pytz==2021.3
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.25
webargs==8.0.1
Werkzeug==2.0.2
```

I have tried resolving this in multiple ways but nothing worked.

I installed MS visual studio build tools 2022, including workload desktop development with C++ but I'm getting the same error... could not build wheels.

Comment: I recommend using the `pymysql` module instead of the `mysqlclient` module. You can find a detailed solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76430550/error-while-install-mysqlclient-package-cpanel-terminal/77756090#77756090). It might be helpful for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

That version of mysqlclient you are trying to install doesn't support Python 3.11.3.

https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/2.0.3/#files

If you look at the link above for mysqlclient 2.0.3, you'll notice that it only supports Python versions from 3.6 to 3.9. Therefore, downgrading your Python to one of these versions should work.