# Error while install MySQLClient package cPanel terminal

Tags: mysql, django, cpanel

Error while install MySQLClient package cPanel terminal.
I am windows user and it's run on windows completely but when upload to cPanel and install mysqlclient it not working

### Error which i get in cpanel terminal

- ((project:3.8)) [shriyamc@callisto project]$ pip install mysqlclient
  > Collecting mysqlclient   Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  > Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Building wheels for collected
  > packages: mysqlclient   Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ...
  > error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  >
  >   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit
  > code: 1   ╰─> [40 lines of output]
  >       mysql_config --version
  >       ['10.5.20']
  >       mysql_config --libs
  >       ['-L/usr/lib64', '-lmariadb', '-pthread', '-ldl', '-lm', '-lpthread', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-lz']
  >       mysql_config --cflags
  >       ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-I/usr/include/mysql/..']
  >       ext_options:
  >         library_dirs: ['/usr/lib64']
  >         libraries: ['mariadb', 'dl', 'm', 'pthread']
  >         extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
  >         extra_link_args: ['-pthread']
  >         include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql', '/usr/include/mysql/..']
  >         extra_objects: []
  >         define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,1,1,'final',0)"), ('**version**', '2.1.1')]
  >       running bdist_wheel
  >       running build
  >       running build_py
  >       creating build
  >       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
  >       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       copying MySQLdb/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       copying MySQLdb/*exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb/constants
  >       copying MySQLdb/constants/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb/constants
  >       copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb/constants
  >       copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb/constants
  >       copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb/constants
  >       copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb/constants
  >       copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb/constants
  >       running build_ext
  >       building 'MySQLdb.*mysql' extension
  >       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
  >       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb
  >       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,1,1,'final',0) -D__version**=2.1.1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/home/shriyamc/virtualenv/project/3.8/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
  >       error: command '/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
  >       [end of output]
  >
  >   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
  > problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for MySQL client
  > Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient Failed to build mysqlclient
  > ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to
  > install pyproject.toml-based projects
  >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in **cpanel**   `cPanel, L.L.C. doesn’t develop or ship Python WSGI web applications,...` .  when using `pip install mysqlclient` pip try to build mysqlclient package into a wheel  but it is not a wheel .

one way you can   install the required dependencies from apt-get (Debian/ Ubuntu) or yum (Red Hat/ CentOS) :

> ```
> # For Debian/ Ubuntu
> sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
>
> # For Red Hat/ CentOS
> sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel
> ```

then run `pip install mysqlclient`

if it didn't work go with **mysql-connector-python** :

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: when I'm hit the command sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel it's give me error    " ((paradise:3.8)) [shriyamc@callisto paradise]$ sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel
bash: sudo: command not found "

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar challenge while installing `mysqlclient` for my Django project on cPanel, and after facing issues, I found a workaround that might help you too.

Instead of using `mysqlclient`, consider using the `pymysql` module. Follow these steps:

1. Install the pymysql module by running:

   ```
   pip install pymysql
   ```
2. In your main Django settings file, add the following lines at the top:

   ```py
   import pymysql
   pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)
   pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
   ```

This configuration allows Django to use pymysql as a substitute for `mysqlclient`. Following these steps, I successfully configured my Django project to connect to a MySQL database.

You can also check out [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNeVaTd_x0M). It guided me through the process, and I hope it proves helpful for you too!

Note: Unlike some web service providers, it might not be necessary to run `sudo` commands for this solution, as it could be restricted by the hosting environment.